# Box plot with 2 variables, changing variables on the x axis

Tags: rename, boxplot, x-axis

I have a boxplot that looks like this:

My x axis has 2 variables (0 and 1) which I want to rename "Low" and "High" respectively but I just can't seem to find the code for this.

[image]

This is the code I used for the boxplot: data$meansplit is the vector on the x axis I want to rename

```html
boxplot(data$threshold_SDT ~ data$meansplit)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have and add the programming language as a tag to your question you are using.